# Non linear constraints over real numbers in Prolog

Tags: prolog, constraints

I am using clpr for constraint logic programming over real numbers in Prolog. Specifically i want to maximise nonlinear expressions, see code below. clpr is limited to linear constraints so the code below does not work (replacing the * with a + works).

Could you please recommend a library for this if there is one?

Cheers/JCR

```
:-use_module(library(clpr)).

main:-
    {Y = X1 * X2 - X3},
    {X1 >= 0, X1 =< 1},
    {X2 >= 0, X2 =< 1},
    {X3 >= 0, X3 =< 1},
    maximize(Y),
    write("Y = "), write(Y), nl,
    write("X1 = "), write(X1), nl,
    write("X2 = "), write(X2), nl,
    write("X3 = "), write(X3).
```

Comment: related: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c068/5a18c07b36a23a8d351898f940f2e0a2c31c.pdf

Comment: related: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/50c3/e4d4c39b54cf0e8cded3002c698358169e07.pdf

Comment: There was a Prolog based solver using Gröbner bases from the Buchberger group